# Maven issue - dependency(class not found exception)

Tags: java, maven, classnotfoundexception, autowired

I'm starting on a new project, and it seems to have some problems related to Maven. When I try to start my web app, it gives errors related to bean factory creation, because cannot find a class referenced in other project. In such scenario, I need to stop the server, run the pom.xml for that other project, run pom.xml for my project and then restart the server. It seems strange to me, if they are related, shoudn't maven run that dependency automatically?

See the error message below:

```
2012-08-03 08:55:01,374 [domain-service:main][ERROR] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'assetService' defined in URL [file:/C:/Springsource/tc-server-6.0.20.domain.service/wtpwebapps/pumpkin-domain-service/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/pumpkin/service/exception/ServiceException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:965)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3934)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:587)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:415)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/pumpkin/service/exception/ServiceException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1890)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:887)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1351)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1230)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1985)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:65)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:958)
    ... 28 more
```

Any help is very appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The exception message is clear enough, try to see if the dependency containing com/pumpkin/service/exception/ServiceException exists in your war

Comment: I can perfectly undertand a class not found exception, that is not the point. This issue is related to Maven, not the class, as explained above.

Comment: post your maven (pom.xml) file

Comment: Have you defined an dependency to the other projects to get the information into your classpath?

Comment: as I said, you should check whether the dependency containing that class exists in your war

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always like to put my answer when I get it so I can help someone that comes to the page looking for a solution... I looked more on the internet and finally found the solution on other [stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822958/maven-spring-java-classnotfoundexception-but-i-know-class-is-there):

> Maven dependencies are not always transitive. If taac-backend-gui
>   declares its dependency on com.wuntee.rsaAuthenticationManager with
>   scope="test" or optional="true", com.wuntee.rsaAuthenticationManager
>   won't automatically become a dependency of com.wuntee.taac Either of
>   these would be consistent with the symptoms you describe.

Cheers!